# jQuery removes first div only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function:

```
function removeDiv() {          
    var topmost = jQuery('.xx');
    var totContent = topmost.find('.zz').length;
    var $target = jQuery('.xx').find('.zz').eq(0);
    if(totContent > 5) {
        $target.hide('slow', function(){ $target.remove(); });
    }
}
```

I use it in my ajax call, to remove extra div then there are more than 5, hovewer it remove first div only once!

And this is how ajax call looks:

```
function saveClubs(array) {
    for(i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    var id = array[i];
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: true,
            url: 'index.php?option=com_events&task=club.save&id=' + id,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery('.xx').append('<div class="zz">'+data+'</div>');
                removeDiv();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: If statement executes only once if condition is true. So first div is removed only.

Comment: If all of these ajax calls are completing around the same time (likely), they're probably all picking up the same `div` while it's in the process of being hidden.

Comment: @SatyaRanjanSahoo: Right, but the OP calls the function repeatedly, so...

Comment: Why a for loop. jQuery offers a more flexible and readible alternative `$.each`

Comment: @PaulRoub: I think you've got it there, nice one. I'd post it as an answer.

Comment: Both `$.ajax()` and `.hide()` return promises. You could easily chain this to prevent any race conditions.

Comment: @Verhaeren Yes, but actually twice. And by the way, I used now .last() instead of .eq(0), so it works correctly, hovewer I need to remove first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Paul Roub's answer, posted as an answer rather than a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489700/jquery-removes-first-div-only-once/27489944#comment43411172_27489700):

The likely problem is that since you're doing a bunch of ajax calls in a loop, they tend to complete at the same time, and so you end up repeated fading out the *same* element (since it's still there until it's done fading).

The *minimal changes* fix would be to, say, add a class as you're fading it out:

```
function removeDiv() {
    // Get the container (I take it there's only one .xx element)
    var topmost = jQuery('.xx');

    // Get the child elements that aren't fading
    var zz = topmost.find('.zz').not('.fading');

    // Too many?
    if(zz.length > 5) {
        // Yup, add 'fading' to the first one and fade it out
        // Note that there's no need for the $target variable
        zz.eq(0).addClass('fading').hide('slow', function(){ $(this).remove(); });
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could select the first X elements that should be removed like in my plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/9ejDVk1EFqdUXT0YkGEq?p=preview

Comment: I didn't have an answer, I just pointed out the problem :-) This is cleaner by far than what I would have suggested.

Comment: @PaulRoub: Team effort! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this:

```
var $target = jQuery('.xx').find('.zz').eq(0);
```

It's always `0 index`.

```
function removeDiv(x) {          
    var topmost = jQuery('.xx');
    var totContent = topmost.find('.zz').length;
    var $target = jQuery('.xx').find('.zz').eq(x);
    if(totContent > 5) {
        $target.hide('slow', function(){ $target.remove(); });
    }
}

function saveClubs(array) {
    for(i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    var id = array[i];
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: true,
            url: 'index.php?option=com_events&task=club.save&id=' + id,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery('.xx').append('<div class="zz">'+data+'</div>');
                removeDiv(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[LIVE EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/qb40p1ts/1/)

**NOTE**

IN the Fiddle above, try to change this `var $target = jQuery('.xx').find('.zz').eq(x);` harcoding the value of `x` to **0** and it'll happen just once.

Comment: This won't work, because the success callbacks close over the **variable** `i`, not the value it had as of when the callbacks were created; by the time the calls to `removeDiv` happen, they'll all use the value of `i` as of the end of the loop (`array.length`). The fiddle only works because the calls are synchronous, but the ajax calls are not. This could be made to work, using various techniques for ensuring that the closures close over something that doesn't change, but in general I find it much more reliable to have the elements carry their state rather than rely on tracking it elsewhere.